# Input checkboxes are unchecking on refresh

Tags: html, css

I created some checkboxes that will check and strike through text. However, if the page is refreshed, it goes back to an unchecked/normal text. How can I prevent that? I've noticed a lot of people search for the opposite to happen but I'd like this info to stay.

HTML:

```
<li><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="strikethrough" value="1"><span>TEXT</span></label></div></li>
<li><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="strikethrough" value="1"><span>TEXT</span></label></div></li>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox {
    margin-left: .25em;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}
.strikethrough:checked + span{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to store the checkbox state somewhere and load it on "document ready" event. You can store the values in browser's local storage.

Here's the untested example that should give you the general idea:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

// On document ready event, set the initial states of the checkboxes
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
    this.checked = window.localStorage.getItem(checkbox.id) || false;
  });
});

// When checkbox state is changed, save it to the localStorage
checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
    window.localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.value);
  });
});
```

Keep in mind that for this example to work, you'll need unique id for each checkbox, since it's used as localStorage key.

You could also store your checkbox states in the session storage, or even cookies, but the local storage seems the most appropriate for this case. You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

P.S. SO snippets cannot use localStorage due to security reasons, so I can't give you a complete example.

Comment: So say if i'm repeating the same text for a different row in a table, would i still need that one to be a different ID? Or could it share the same ID as the previous one? A lot of these repeat to the point i feel like i'd reach like 60 something IDs

Comment: IDs are supposed unique identifiers of the element, so regardless of localStorage, you should never have duplicated IDs on your page.

Now to answer your question: I simply used `checkbox.id` as localStorage key, you can edit that part to fit your particular case. localStorage is just a convenient key-value storage. :)

Comment: @Brandon: If one of these answers helped you, please don't forget to mark the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question - if you're writing to the *local* storage, does that mean anyone else that goes to the page won't see what was previously there?

Comment: Yes, local storage data is kept in the browser, which means that it is not shared between users. 

In order to have data shared between users, you'll need to store data on the server and serve it when rendering page.

Comment: Well snap, this just got more difficult.. do you have any insight to that? (storing on the server)

Comment: It's a whole other matter. :) I'm guessing you are just using a simple *.html file to serve your content, in which case there's no way we can cover everything using SO comments. Sorry. :(

Comment: Correct.. just a simple cms page.. or what i thought was simple. Well hey, i appreciate your help!

Comment: Anytime. Hope you'll find solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want the checkbox to be checked by default, you just need to use `checked` attribute

More information regarding [checked attribute for input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Including checked attributes gives us the **following HTML**

```
<li><div class="checkbox"><label><input checked type="checkbox" class="strikethrough" value="1"><span>TEXT</span></label></div></li>
<li><div class="checkbox"><label><input checked type="checkbox" class="strikethrough" value="1"><span>TEXT</span></label></div></li>
```

However, if you want to store the value users previously set, you'll need to go with cookie or session storage

Comment: No, not checked by default. They should remain unchecked how they do now but if someone checks that box, i'd like it to stay on refresh. Right now it removes it and it goes back to being unchecked.

Comment: As I said in the answer, if you want to store the value users previously set, you'll need to go with cookie or session storage. This involves javascript

Answer (score 0):

Another way for you to do this without any `storage` would be to create an object (or an array) which hosts the checkboxes values. You can then `JSON.stringify` that object and add it to the current url.

On refresh you can check if there is a query-string parameter and from it you can do `JSON.parse` and then re-check the boxes.

This also helps when you want to send a direct link to someone with an already set state.

This way you do not care if a user wipes his local storage or is on another machine with your link. It should work everywhere.

Just make sure you `encode/decodeURIComponent()` the `stringified` result.